# Bash script help substitution

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ubuntu-mate

Is there a way so I don't have to manually change maxruntime?

So that --timeout "time" = maxruntime

```
SCRIPTS="/home/andy/bin/CPU_Stress_Test.txt"

command="/usr/bin/stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 15s"
maxruntime=15s

rm $SCRIPTS
echo $command

$command >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
watchpid=$!
date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" >> $SCRIPTS
sensors -f | grep "temp4" >> $SCRIPTS
sensors -f | grep "fan1" >>  $SCRIPTS

/bin/sleep "$maxruntime"

if [ -d "/proc/$watchpid" ]
then
        echo "Max runtime exceeded, killing PID $watchpid"

        if /bin/kill -9 "$watchpid" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
        then
                echo "Killed."
                exit 0
        else
                echo "Could not kill, please investigate manually."
                exit 1
        fi
fi
date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" >> $SCRIPTS
sensors -f | grep "temp4" >> $SCRIPTS
sensors -f | grep "fan1" >>  $SCRIPTS
```

Comment: Pass it in as a variable, if I get you query correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes on your code:

- when you want to store a command in a variable, use an array (see: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050))

  ```
  command=(/usr/bin/stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout "$maxruntime")
  # then execute it like
  "${command[@]}"         # with the quotes!
  ```
- always quote your variables, unless you know exactly why you want them unquoted (see: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells))
- you have some duplicated code, so use a function:

  ```
  get_sensor_info() {
      date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"

      # if you don't care about order of "temp4" or "fan1"
      sensors -f | grep -E 'temp4|fan1'

      # or if you do care about the order, then you still only need to call sensors once
      sensor_info=$(sensors -f)
      echo "$sensor_info" | grep temp4
      echo "$sensor_info" | grep fan1
  }

  get_sensor_info >> "$stress_log"
  ```
- don't use ALLCAPS variable names, leave those for the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=xyz` and then wonder why your script is broken.
- you don't need to repeat yourself with `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` --> `>/dev/null 2>&` or the bash-specific `&>/dev/null`
- use https://www.shellcheck.net to check your code for errors.

Comment: maxruntime=15s
command=(/usr/bin/stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout "$maxruntime") "${command[@]}" & watchpid=$! I got stress: info: [3447] dispatching hogs: 8 cpu, 4 io, 2 vm, 0 hdd
Max runtime exceeded, killing PID 3447
stress: info: [3447] successful run completed in 15s
Could not kill, please investigate manually. @glenn jackman

Answer (score 2):

Just switch the order of the assignments for `command` and `maxruntime` and substitute it in `command`.

```
maxruntime="15s"
command="/usr/bin/stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout ${maxruntime}"
```